# System network services not compatible

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, system-requirements

There are several other older posts regarding this issue but suggested workarounds (most not fixes) are not resolving for me.

I started with v12.04 and had the issue. I WAS able to access the internet but System/network gives the error. I can close the error and am left with a popup that only included proxy configuration...no wireless info, etc.

I uninstalled v12.04 and installed 14.04 with same results.

I also repaired/upgraded network-manager with apt-get.

Finally, I have tried to start network-manager manually...no difference.

Does anyone have anything to suggest?

Comment: What network are you fighting with? Is it wired or wireless. if it is wireless, please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: I've run the command but with Xterm I am unable to copy in order to paste.  It identifies my network card and the kernel driver in use. Keep in mind I'm not necessarily "fighting" a network...I have internet access. I just don't understand why many of us get that error about services not being compatible with this version

Comment: You can use gnome-terminal instead. Or select text and post it with middle click.